# How do I remove, update, and search two different lists that are independent?

Tags: python, list

I have a program that has two lists; one for name (inventory) and one that holds the qty. How do I remove, update, and search by the name (inventory) list and cause the appropriate action to happen with the qty list. For example, if I have a list of five items and the five qty's are in prop order in a different list. If I delete item three, how do I delete the qty of the item as well? Below is the full code:

```
import os


name = []

qty = []
class Inventory:
    def __init__(self,desc,unit):
        self.description = desc
        self.units = unit

class Totals:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory=[]
    def adding(self,inventory):
        #adding item to list
        self.inventory.append(inventory)

    def show_items(self):
        if not self.inventory:
            return
        print("{:<15}{:<25}".format(" "*9,"Description","Units in inventory"))
        print("-"*75)
        for c,i in enumerate(self.inventory,1):
            print("{:<15}{:<25}{:<25}{:<10}".format("Item #"+str(c),i.description,i.units))
        print("-"*75)


def menuDisplay():
    print ('=============================')
    print ('= Inventory Management Menu =')
    print ('=============================')
    print ('(1) Add New Item to Inventory')
    print ('(2) Remove Item from Inventory')
    print ('(3) Update Inventory')
    print ('(4) Search Item in Inventory')
    print ('(5) Print Inventory Report')
    print ('(99) Quit')
    CHOICE = int(input("Enter choice: "))
    menuSelection(CHOICE)

def menuSelection(CHOICE):

    if CHOICE == 1:
        print('Adding Inventory')
        print('================')
        new_name = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
        name.append(new_name)
        new_qty = int(input("Enter the quantity of the item: "))
        qty.append(new_qty)
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
            menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
    elif CHOICE == 2:
        print('Removing Inventory')
        print('==================')
        removing = input('Enter the item name to remove from inventory: ')
        name.remove(removing)
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
            menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
    elif CHOICE == 3:
        print('Updating Inventory')
        print('==================')
        input('Enter the item to update: ')
        update = int(input("Enter the updated quantity. Enter 5 for additional or -5 for less: "))
    if update == 5:
        print()
    elif update == -5:
        print()
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
            menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
        updateInventory()
    elif CHOICE == 4:
        print('Searching Inventory')
        print('===================')
        search = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
        if search in search:
            print ('Item:     ', item_description)
            print ('Quantity: ', item_quantity)
            print ('----------')
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
            menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
        searchInventory()
    elif CHOICE == 5:
        print('Current Inventory')
        print('=================')
        input('Enter the name of the item: ')
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
            menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
        printInventory()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
    
def printInventory():
    InventoryFile = open('Inventory.txt', 'r')
    item_description = InventoryFile.readline()
    print ('Current Inventory')
    print ('-----------------')
    while item_description != '':
        item_quantity = InventoryFile.readline()
        item_description = item_description.rstrip('\n')
        item_quantity = item_quantity.rstrip('\n')
        print ('Item:     ', item_description)
        print ('Quantity: ', item_quantity)
        print ('----------')
        item_description = InventoryFile.readline()
    InventoryFile.close()

    CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
            menuDisplay()
    else:
        exit()
    
menuDisplay()
```

I believe the adding option works, and so does the removing, but I do not know how to delete the qty along with the item name.

Comment: Use objects to group your info, dictionaries to map it to useful keys

Comment: 2 separate lists is a very bad way of monitoring your data. You would better use a dictionary, or a list of tuples-pairs, or a list of lists-pairs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do. You'll need to know 2 new functions, though.

### **1st New Function**

`.remove` removes the item that matches whatever you're removing. However, in your case, I think you're looking for `.pop()` [pop](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/pop)

`.pop()`  takes in a number, which is the index of the item you want to delete.

### **2nd Function**

Now you'll have to know `.index`, which returns the index of a string you input into the function. [index](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index)

### **Putting It Together**

Now that you know these 2 functions, it's easy! Use `.index()` on the first list, then `.pop` on the second one!

```
lis = ["hello", "bye", "sigh"]
lis2 = [10, 20, 30]

takeout = input("What do you want to delete?")
indexdel = lis.index(takeout)
lis.pop(indexdel)
lis2.pop(indexdel)
```

That will delete both of them! Now, apply to your own code.

For your purposes, it would be:

```
    elif CHOICE == 2:
        print('Removing Inventory')
        print('==================')
        removing = input('Enter the item name to remove from inventory: ')
        indexdel = name.index(removing)
        name.pop(indexdel)
        qty.pop(indexdel)
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
```

**ALSO! Addressing the comments about one single object**

That would've been my first move too, but I think that it's a bit confusing at first. However, I can show that way too!

Let's make a class that will store these 2 values.

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, name, qty):
        self.name = name
        self.qty = qty
```

Now, you can create several objects in a list like:

```
item = []
item.append(Foo("hello", 50))
item.append(Foo("bye", 100))

def delitem(name):
    for i in item:
        if i.name == name:
            item.remove(i)
```

Comment: Yep! No problem!